# Accessing External Modules

Tags: vba, excel

I have about 8 different workbooks that all have the same modules in them.  Unfortunately, the workbooks need to be separate. I have four modules in each workbook. Whenever someone finds a problem with the workbook such as an error I did not catch originally in the code, I have to make the correction to all of the workbooks.  Presently, I make the correction in one of the modules, export it, and then delete the bad module from the other workbooks and import the corrected module(s).  This is time consuming and I am hoping to find a way to either quickly import the updated modules or access the modules from a centralized location on the network drive.  Is this possible?

I have scoured the internet but either I am not typing in the correct search or no one seems to have this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If all of these workbooks reside on your machine and are used mostly by you, then you could put the macros in your personal.xls file and have only one copy on any of the various spreadsheets.  There's a good tutorial about the personal.xls on Ron de Briun's site:

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/personal.htm

Part of your question suggests that the workbooks might reside on other computers and you are then updating and distributing the new versions.  If that is the case you might try using the method suggested by Charles Williams in this Stack Overflow question:

[How to get VBA excel addin .xlam to replace itself by a remote updated .xlam?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577158/how-to-get-vba-excel-addin-xlam-to-replace-itself-by-a-remote-updated-xlam)

Then you would simply create a shared add-in and replace the file in one location referenced by the xla/xlam. Ozgrid has a decent primer on creating add-ins:

http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-add-in-create.htm

Hope that at least some of this helps with your problem.

Comment: The workbooks are all on our network so no one has a copy on his or her hard drive.  I could possibly create an add-in on my computer to update the modules but I need to find a way to automate updating the modules.  That's why I was hoping there was a way to point to the module location and have the workbook read the module from the drive rather than having import the updated modules.